# dataSource sql server Connection from solr

Tags: sql-server, solr

Having problem to connect to sql server from solr.

I have tried following connections

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="ds1"
driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=189021-resurs;integratedSecurity=true;responseBuffering=adaptive;"   
readOnly="true"
/>


<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"  
   url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\ARBETSDATOR\SQLEXPRESS;integratedSecurity=true;databaseName=189021-resurs"/>
```

Im trying to use integratedSecurity=true, is that ok?

tcp/ip is enabled.

I have seen variations of following part of the connectionstring, should it be:
jdbc:sqlserver://ARBETSDATOR\SQLEXPRESS

Or just localhost:
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;

?

When using jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; i get following:

Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT * FROM Members Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:270)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:411)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:476)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:457)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT * FROM Members Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:410)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:323)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:231)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT * FROM Members Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.(JdbcDataSource.java:279)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:236)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:40)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:469)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:408)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: TCP/IP-anslutningen till värddatorn localhost, port 1433 misslyckades. Fel: "Connection refused: connect. Verifiera anslutningsegenskaperna. Kontrollera att en instans av SQL Server körs på värddatorn som accepterar TCP/IP-anslutningar på porten och att ingen brandvägg blockerar TCP-anslutningar till porten.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:149)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:392)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:40)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.(JdbcDataSource.java:266)

Its basically saying that the tcp/ip connection to sql server failed. I have made sure that its enabled so that cannot be it.

When using jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\ARBETSDATOR\SQLEXPRESS;

I receive following error message:

Exception while processing: member document : SolrInputDocument(fields: []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT * FROM Members Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.(JdbcDataSource.java:279)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:236)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:40)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:469)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:408)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:323)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:231)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:411)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:476)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:457)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Anslutningen till värddatorn localhost, den namngivna instansen arbetsdator\sqlexpress, misslyckades. Fel: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out. Verifiera server- och instansnamn och kontrollera att ingen brandvägg blockerar UDP-trafik till port 1434. Kontrollera även för SQL Server 2005 eller senare att tjänsten SQL Server Browser körs på värddatorn.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:3589)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:1225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:972)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:149)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:392)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:40)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.(JdbcDataSource.java:266)

Some help with this would be extremely appreciated

**UPDATE**

New error message:

```
Exception while processing: member document : SolrInputDocument(fields:[]):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT * FROM Members Processing Document # 1
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:279)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:236)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:40)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:469)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:408)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:323)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:231)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:411)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:476)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:457)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Drivrutinen är inte konfigurerad för integrerad autentisering. ClientConnectionId:eb7b4593-8238-4d7a-92bc-7ffb520e3d9c
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<init>(AuthenticationJNI.java:60)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2229)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:149)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:129)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:392)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:40)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:266)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<clinit>(AuthenticationJNI.java:35)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2229)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:142)
```

One line is not in English, it says that the driver is not configured for integrated authentication.

Comment: If sqljdbc_auth.dll can not be loaded. Do this: copy `sqljdbc_auth.dll` to `C:\Windows\System32`, then restart the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string should look like this: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=189021-resurs;integratedSecurity=true;

Then also check if by default MS SQL Server Express is configured to use dynamic TCP/IP ports, like named instances. Go into the Sql Server Configuration Manager
open SQL SERVER 2005 (this may be different for you) Network Configuration
open Protocols for SQLEXPRESS
open TCP/IP properties
on the IP ADDRESSES tab, check at the bottom if "TCP Dynamic Ports" has a value.

if so, clear the value and leave that field blank.  Then change "TCP Port" to 1433 or whatever port you decide.

Comment: If you read the exception :- Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path. You're using a JDBC driver that is dependent on a native SQL Server driver and need to add a path to the DLL it's dependent on (sqljdbc_auth.dll) to your library path in java. You need to copy it from your mssqlinstall =>/sqljdbc_2.0/enu/auth/x64 to same place as your ms sql driver jar file.

Comment: i copied the file but still same error:  the driver is not configured for integrated authentication. AND no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Comment: where did you copy it. you need to make sure that Solr is able to get to it, by making sure this is in classpath.

Comment: Hi MikeALike234 ! How did you solve it ? Have you added the dll directly in Solr imports ?

  <lib path="${solr.dist.home:}/../solr/lib/jars/sqljdbc41.jar"/>
    <lib path="${solr.dist.home:}/../solr/lib/jars/sqljdbc_auth.dll"/>

I have not check at all if it make sense to add it there, I have not checked how the classpath is loaded for Solr